# With bottle.py, how do I properly render static file requests of templates?

Tags: python, bottle

I am experimenting with bottle.py, and I'm coming across some problems with requesting static templates vs rendering them.

I have some basic routes:

```
@route("/feed")
def show_feed():
    # query database, calculate things, etc.
    # code to show feed (which is dynamic)

@route("/submit")
def show_submit():
    # query database, calculate things, etc.
    # code to show submit

@route("/<filename:path>")
def serve_static(filename):
    # code to simply return static files
```

I also have some templates:

```
views/submit.html
views/feed.html
```

There are no problems with the web server itself. It works as it is told. The problem is when I use links in my templates, as usual, to go from page to page:

```
<a href="feed.html">Go back to the feed</a>
```

When a user clicks on that link or manually enters ".../feed.html" or ".../submit.html", the URL `.../feed.html` is requested instead of `/feed`, and Bottle routes that to the `serve_static(filename)` function. As a result, the template is not rendered - instead, the static template is returned, complete with ugly things like "{{article[0]}}" and "% end % end".

**How can I get Bottle to render these templates properly?**

Is there a way for Bottle to know when to render templates when they are requested as static files? Is it considered an okay practice to change `href` attributes to what the server should expect? Is there something I'm not considering?

Comment: Why are you putting the templates in the `static` directory, instead of in a `views` directory, as suggested in [the documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#templates)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that note. I did just change the `static` directory to `views` but it had no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is very simply that

```
<a href="feed.html">
```

has a wrong `href` given your URL pattern.  Just change it to

```
<a href="feed">
```

It's also a good idea, as BrenBarn suggested, to move the templates into their own separate subdirectories, away from the one from which you want to serve truly static public files.  However, per se, that wouldn't solve your problem -- you'd just get a 404 on clicks on the link in question.  The core issue is fixing that `<a>`'s `href`!

Comment: The more I typed this question out, the more that became obvious to me. However, I wasn't sure if it was a standard practice to link to web application routes rather than strictly files - I hadn't ever seen or read anything about that. Thanks for pointing out what I should have accepted as obvious!

Comment: Always link to the URL you desire to reach!  Anyway, glad I helped.